# PHP imagecreatefromjpeg fails on large image

Tags: php, image, gd

my image has about 5000x3000 pixels and I want to use the `imagecreatefromjpeg` function in PHP, however the image keeps just empty. When I try it with a smaller one It is working perfectly. I tried to set the `memory_limit` to 800M and also `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);`.

My code:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$img1 = imagecreatefromjpeg("1.jpg");
$img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg('2.jpg');

imagecopy($img1, $img2, 605, 109, 0, 0, 200, 200);

imagepng($img1);
imagedestroy($img1);
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Errors:
[image: Errors]

What else can I do

Comment: What do you mean by *"empty"*? Is it returning boolean `false`? Do you have error reporting set to `E_ALL` and `display_errors` enabled?

Comment: Have you also adjusted server file upload size, and post size?
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#96227 Any error in php logs file?

Comment: @ChrisChen only really applicable if OP is uploading the image but that could definitely be the case :)

Comment: I just tried increasing the post and file upload size, however it didn't help. (Edited my post).

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')`

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: ini_set ('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1); according to the refered question